# Exception Message in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Here I Want to show exception message like "Request Parameter is not found".
Here is my code.

```
use Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException;

 protected $order;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order
) {
    $this->order = $order;
  }

public function getorderaddresslist($orderid) {
    try {
    $order = $this->order->load($orderid);
    $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress()->getData();
    $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress()->getData();
    $address = array(
            'addresses' => [
            'shippingAddress' => $shippingAddress,
            'billingAddress' => $billingAddress
            ]
        );

      json_encode($address); 
     }
    catch(\Exception $e){
       throw new StateException(__('Request Parameter is not matched.'));
    }
```

How i can show a message if request parameter is not matched.can any help me.

Answer (score 4):

You can use message manger to show error message whenever exception will come.

```
use Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException;

protected $order;

public function __construct(

    \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order,
    \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager

) {

    $this->order = $order;
    $this->messageManager = $messageManager;

  }

public function getorderaddresslist($orderid) {

    try {

    $order = $this->order->load($orderid);

    $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress()->getData();

    $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress()->getData();

    $address = array(
            'addresses' => [
            'shippingAddress' => $shippingAddress,
            'billingAddress' => $billingAddress
            ]
        );


      json_encode($address); 

     }

    catch(\Exception $e){

       $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Request Parameter is not matched.'));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use message manager in the catch block to show the message as shown below;

```
class Example
{
    protected $_messageManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager
    ) {
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
    }

    public function method( ) {
        ..
        try{
            ....
         }
       catch(\Exception $e){
        $message = '...';
        $this->_messageManager->addError($message);
        }
    }
}
```